# Convert from NSMultableArray to NSInteger

Tags: objective-c

When I try to convert part of NSMutableArray to NSInteger, I get nine-digit number(maybe number of sector), not value of this part.

```
NSInteger i = [_tableData[1][@"likes"][@"count"] intValue];
```

_tableData - converted answer from vk.com server

```
NSMutableArray *_tableData;
//------------------

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [[VKConnector sharedInstance]
    setDelegate:self];
    [[VKConnector sharedInstance] startWithAppID:@"3541027"
    permissons:@[@"wall"]];
}

#pragma mark - VKConnectorDelegate

- (void)VKConnector:(VKConnector *)connector accessTokenRenewalSucceeded:(VKAccessToken *)accessToken
{
    [[VKUser currentUser] setDelegate:self];
    [[VKUser currentUser] wallGet:@{@"owner_id":@"-44554509",@"count":@"100"}];
}

#pragma mark - VKRequestDelegate

- (void)VKRequest:(VKRequest *)request response:(id)response
{
    _tableData = response[@"response"];
    [_mainList reloadData];
}
```

[image]

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", [_tableData[1][@"likes"][@"count"]);` what does it print ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not converting a `NSMutableArray`, you're converting whatever object is contained. And even then it's a little confusing:

```
NSInteger i = [_tableData[1][@"likes"][@"count"] intValue];
```

...so `tableData` presumably contains a dictionary at index 1, which in turn contains *another* dictionary under the `likes` key, which then contains a `NSValue` under the `count` key. That's what I'm *assuming*, but it seems quite likely that in fact your nested array/dictionary contains something else.

You should debug your app to establish exactly what object you're accessing. You can do this using breakpoints, or by adding some logging statements (or both).

Comment: I cant post images, so i post link here.
https://pp.vk.me/c308723/v308723522/8bf5/qkJ1Jk8XnGo.jpg